# React Router not rendering correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I had this working before, but I've made some changes in my app structure which has broken the routes. If I manually go to the route in the browser it works (the correct content loads). The href attribute is not rendering in the html.

I have a warning message in my console:
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `to` supplied to `Link`.

I don't nderstand why it's invalid.
What can I do to improve the code and fix the problem?

Index.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Header from './Header';
import Routes from './Routes';

import '../less/imports.less';

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <main>
      <Routes />
    </main>
  </div>
);

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  ReactDOM.render(
    (
      <App />
    ), document.getElementById('app'),
  );
}
```

Routes.jsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import About from './About';
import Blog from './Blog';

class Routes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: 'active',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <ul className="block-group">
              <li className={this.state.active}><Link to={Dashboard}>Dashboard</Link></li>
              <li><Link to={About}>About</Link></li>
              <li><Link to={Blog}>Blog</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/blog" component={Blog} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed this by changing the to href to the actual route strings. Not sure how it worked before.

```js
<li className={this.state.active}><Link to="/">Dashboard</Link></li>
<li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
<li><Link to="/blog">Blog</Link></li>
```